# Autoscaling with AWS load-balancer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I want to use Amazon's load balancer with autoscaling. I found that I need to make an autoscaling group and then need to launch instances with that, but can't I use existing instances in autoscaling? Is there any other technique I can use for autoscaling?

Comment: No, you can't use existing instances for auto-scaling, but you can create an AMI from an existing instance and use that for the autoscaling group.

Answer (score 0):

Autoscaling involves creating new instances as load increases and decreases. For this you need an AMI image.

You can add an existing instance to an elastic load balancer but it won't be part of autoscaling.